# What are these circle-like things on my spectrogram?

Tags: phonetics

[image]

Hello. I know that it is probably hard to see because it's a small picture. If you zoom in a little on your internet browser you should be able to seem them better. At the end of the selected interval (EH1), underneath the semi-sinusoidal wave form, on the spectrogram, you can see two rows of ripples. In fact, you can see them throughout the entire window, but they are more visible where I have indicated.

Does anyone know what these are?

This recording was done on an H4n and 44100Hz in a attenuated booth. The H4n was plugged into the AC wall charger.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what program is this?

Comment: @PatMuchmore It's the 'Praat' application for analyzing sounds.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell what exactly you're talking about -- not the semi-sinusoidal part in the waveform at the end of EH1, and not the pattern of 4 dots throughout the spectrogram (the formants). If you could use a drawing program to circle the stuff in question, that would be useful. The roundest thing at the end of the selection (EH1) is in the waveform, and that is basically the last few flops of the vocal folds vibrating during /ð/, but with most of the energy at the fundamental.

[EDIT]

If you mean rows and not columns, then I assume that is the small red dots, which are marks (formant tracking is on). If you meant columns, and there are about 7 of them visible near the circles you drew, those are individual harmonics. You also see them at regular intervals in the light areas before the circled part. I put in vertical lines separating the things I think you're talking about.

[image]

Comment: I gave my post a better explanation and  drew two circles whereI see the ripples. Try zooming in a bit on your web browser. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out what the ripple-like things are. It's just the image rendering on my 2009 mac. When I use a better computer you can't see them.

Thanks

Comment: I am skeptical of that explanation, since in my experience, differences in video technology have virtually no effect on Praat images. I suspect that the reason for different appearances on different computers is that the analysis settings differ between the computers, thus I would check the settings.